# Connecting Visual Studio Online Account to SharePoint Server Hosted On-Premises

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, azure-devops

We have a Visual Studio Online account and a SharePoint server hosted on-premises. Is there an easy way to connect the two like the SharePoint portals that are available for TFS and on-premises SharePoint 2013?

The team has a few source control and project management tool novices, I trying to create a simple way they can add projects to a portal using portal settings.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

At this time, there is not a way to setup integration between a SharePoint server on-premises and Visual Studio Online.  However, you can include links/URLs to document in work items to documents stored in SharePoint which is something we frequently do.